# Estou tentando passar a minha id do banco de dados para chamar uma imagem em outro diretorio

Tags: php, banco-de-dados

Estou tendo alguns problemas para inserir uma imagem no site, já fiz o upload mas não estou conseguindo chamar ela do diretório com php.

Estou recebendo dois error:

1-Notice: Undefined index: arquivo in C:\xampp\htdocs\Painel de controle\produtos.php on line 7

2-Recoverable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\Painel de controle\produtos.php on line 96

O cidigo usado:

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'conn_prod.php';
require 'processa_img.php';

$id = mysqli_query($conn_prod,"SELECT id FROM necessaires;");
```

?>

Aqui vem parte do html

```
<div class="log_prods"> 
<div class="corpo_log">
<?php

//RECEBER O NUMERO DA PAGINA
    $pagina_atual   =   filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'pagina');

     $pagina = (!empty($pagina_atual))  ?  $pagina_atual : 1;

//SETAR A QUANTIDADE DE ITENS POR PAGINA
     $quant_result_pg = 5;

//CALCULAR O INICIO DA VISUALIZAÇÃO
     $inicio = ($quant_result_pg * $pagina) - $quant_result_pg;



    $pegar_result = "SELECT * FROM necessaires LIMIT $inicio, $quant_result_pg";
    $result_produtos = mysqli_query($conn_prod, $pegar_result);

        while ($row_produto = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_produtos)) {
            # code...
            echo "<section><span>Tema :</span>" . $row_produto['tema'] . "<br>
                  <span>ID :</span>" . $row_produto['id_nec'] . "<div class='cont_img-prod'><img src=" ?><?php echo "upload/$id/";               "</div></section><hr>";
        };
        ?>
        <?php

//  PAGINAÇÃO - SOMAR A QUANTIDADE DE USUARIOS
    $result_pg = "SELECT COUNT(id) AS num_result FROM necessaires";
    $resultado_pg = mysqli_query($conn_prod, $result_pg);
    $row_pg = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_pg);
    //echo $row_pg['num_result'];

//QUANTIDADE DE PAGINAS

    $quantidade_pg = ceil($row_pg['num_result'] / $quant_result_pg);
    ?>
</div>
    <div class="cont_setas"><div class="setas_">
    <?php

//LIMITAR OS LINKS ANTES E DEPOIS
    $max_links = 1;
    echo "<a href='produtos.php?pagina=1'><i class='pag_pri fas fa-angle-double-left'></i></a>";

        for ($pag_ant = $pagina - $max_links; $pag_ant <= $pagina - 1; $pag_ant ++) { 
            # code...
            if ($pag_ant >= 1){

                echo "<a href='produtos.php?pagina=$pag_ant'>$pag_ant</a>";
            }
        }

    echo "$pagina";

    for($pag_dep = $pagina + 1; $pag_dep <= $pagina + $max_links; $pag_dep ++){

                if ($pag_dep <= $quantidade_pg) {
                    # code...
                    echo "<a href='produtos.php?pagina=$pag_dep'>$pag_dep</a>";
                }
    }

    echo "<a href='produtos.php?pagina=$quantidade_pg'><i class='pag_ult fas fa-angle-double-right'></i></a>";
?>
    </div></div>
```

Agradeço a ajuda desde já.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, na parte do img src você precisa concaternar, você esta colocando a variavel $id como se fosse um texto. seria algo assim:

De uma olhada em concatenacao em PHP –

Comment: muito obrigado, o primeiro erro foi resolvi mas o segundo não e é exatamente esse segundo que não faço a minima ideia do que seja

Comment: poderia mostrar exatamente qual a linha esta dando o erro? Poderia colocar a linha 96 da pagina produtos.php

Comment: echo "<section><span>Tema :</span>" . $row_produto['tema'] . "<br>
       <span>ID :</span>" . $row_produto['id_nec'] . "<div class='cont_img-prod'><img src=" .'upload/$id' ">; ?></div></section><hr>";

Comment: o erro que tem me retornado: Recoverable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\Painel de controle\produtos.php on line 7 - é a primeira vez que me deparo com ele, fui pesquisar no google para tentar entender melhor mas ele só me apresentou 3 resultados que não foram tão uteis.

Comment: Ah sim, achei o erro! Na parte di img src você precisa concaternar, você esta colocando a variavel $id como se fosse um texto. seria algo assim: <img src="upload.'$id'."> . De uma olhada em concatenacao em PHP

Comment: consegui!! Muito Obrigado!!

Comment: Por nada, vou alterar a resposta! Você poderia colcoar como resposta correta? Obrigada